# How to express an equation as a vector?

Tags: vectors

I haven't done maths for a while, and this problem confuses me:

$V = \{p(x) = a_0 + a_1x + a_2x^2 + a_3x^3; a_0, \ldots, a_3 \in \mathbb{R}\}$

a) Show explicitly that $V$ is a vector space.

b) Are the following vectors linearly independent? What is the dimension of the vector space?

$p_1(x) = x^2 - 2x$

$p_2(x) = 7x^2 - x^3$

$p_3(x) = 8x^2 + 11$

My first question would be: how to interpret for example $p_1(x)$ as a vector? I mean $x^2 - 2x$ doesn't come up as a straight line, so how do I interpret such function and in general other polynomials as a vector?

Thank you very much for your answers.

J.

Comment: General vector spaces are mathematical constructs satisfying the properties mentioned in Henry's answer. They need not be expressible as an ordered tuple like you are familiar with in the vector space $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Answer (score 1):

A **vector** is simply an element of a **vector space**.  The thought that they must be "straight lines" is complete nonsense.  Although in euclidean space ($\mathbb{R}^n$), they can be graphically represented as rays from the origin with specified magnitude, this does not need to be the case in general vector spaces such as this one.

Here, we are looking at a subspace of the vector space of polynomial functions, what many authors write as $\mathbb{P}_3$ (though some write as $\mathbb{P}_4$).

To check that it is in fact a vector space, you must show the following:

- Given two elements in our space, $f$ and $g$, show that $f+g$ is also in our space.
- Given an element in our space, $f$, and a scalar $\alpha$ from our scalar field (commonly taken as $\mathbb{R}$, but it varies on context), show that $\alpha f$ is also in our space.
- Commutativity of addition ($f+g = g+f$)
- Associativity of addition ($f+(g+h) = (f+g)+h$)
- Distributivity of multiplication ($\alpha(f+g) = \alpha f + \alpha g$)

  and a few others similar to the above.  In practice, usually the only things needed to be checked are the first two properties since commutativity and distributivity properties usually are inherited from a larger space that we are working in.

So, checking the first property, if you have $f=a_0 + a_1x+ a_2x^2 + a_3x^3$ and you have $g=b_0+b_1x+b_2x^2+b_3x^3$, is it true that $f+g$ can be written as some $f+g=c_0 + c_1x+ c_2x^2+c_3x^3$?

What about $\alpha f$?

---

This particular vector space can be described using the standard basis vectors $\{1,x,x^2,x^3\}$ (but this is not the only choice of basis that is allowed or useful).  Proving that these vectors span the space is trivial.  Proving that they are in fact linearly independent is a bit more interesting, but follows immediately from the fundamental theorem of algebra.

Suppose that $c_0\cdot 1 + c_1\cdot x + c_2\cdot x^2 + c_3\cdot x^3 = 0$ for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$.  If any of $c_0,c_1,c_2,c_3$ are nonzero, this would cause a contradiction as that would suggest that the above equation has infinitely many roots, but by the fundamental theorem of algebra, we know that there should be at most three roots.

As to the dimension of your polynomial space, remember that dimension is defined as the number of vectors in a basis for that space.

If you prefer writing things as "vectors" what you are used to using matrix notation, you could interpret $x^2-2x$ as $(0)\cdot 1 + (-2)\cdot x + (1)\cdot x^2 + (0)\cdot x^3$ and write it as $[0~-\!2~1~0]$ and use methods you are familiar with.

A row reduction argument then will prove or disprove the linear independence of the given vectors.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, it does help me to get it a bit better though it is still very abstract to me. In case of f + g, would it be enough to prove that f + g is in V by writing: f(x) + g(x) = (a0 + a1x + a2x2 + a3x3) + (b0x + b1x + b2x2 + b3x3) = (a0 + b0) + (a1 + b1)x + (a2 + b2)x2 + (a3 + b3)x3?

Comment: (I guess I would additionnally have to state that, like a0...a3, b0...b3 € R, so any addition of those number € R as well, right?)

Comment: Just remember that a vector you are used to as $v=\begin{bmatrix}1\\3\\0\\2\end{bmatrix}$ is simply a convenient way to write $v= 1e_1 + 3e_2 + 0e_3 + 2e_4$ where $e_1,e_2,\dots$ are the standard basis vectors.  The only difference with this problem to earlier problems involving more traditional vectors is that they are removing the crutch of matrix notation.  As to your proof that $f+g$ is in your vector space, yes that is absolutely correct, noting that by adding two real numbers you again get a real number.

Comment: Thank you very much, you have been helpful to me. :)

Comment: I have one more question concerning b): to find out if the vectors are linearly independent (or not), do I "just" have to prove that a0x11 + a1 (-2x) + a2  (16x2) + a3  (-x3) = 0 can be satisfied only if a0...a3 = 0?

Comment: Looking again at what Henry said, I guess what I just wrote was wrong, and that it should instead be: 11v + (-2λ)x + (7u + v)x2 + (-u)x3 = 0; if λ = u = v = 0 is the only solution possible, then the vectors are linearly independent. Is that right?

Comment: Okay I guess I figured it out, but would you mind confirming it to me so that I can feel assured about the process? Thank you in advance: I must find if there are scalars ○,□ and ◇ not all equal to 0, so that ○p1 + □p2 + ◇p3 = 0. Developing the equation, I reach (-□)x3 + (○ + 7□ + 8◇)x2 + (-2○)x + 11◇ = 0. SolvIng the set of solutions shows me that ○ = □ = ◇ = 0 is the only solution, therefore the vectors are linearly independent.

Comment: (Sorry for the weird symbols, I'm writing from a tablet)

Comment: Yes, that seems correct.  With practice, one can spot that they are linearly independent by the fact p2 is the only one of them to have a 3rd order term, p1 is the only one of them to have a first order term, and p3 is the only one of them to have a constant term.

Comment: That makes sense. Thank you very much, your answers really help me to make progress :)

Answer (score 0):

V satisfies the properties of addition commutativity, addition associativity, multiplication associativity, additive identity($0 + 0x + 0x^2 + 0x^3 \in V$), additive inverse, multiplicative identity($1 \in \mathbb{R}$), and multiplication distributivity, so it is a vector space. A vector space does not have to be a set of directions and magnitudes.

A basis for this vector space would be $\{1, x, x^2, x^3\}$. Any element of $V$ can be expressed as a linear combination of these four polynomials. The size of a basis is equal to the dimension, so $\operatorname{dim}V = 4$.

If $p_1, p_2, p_3$ are linearly independent, $\lambda = \mu = \nu = 0$ would be the only solution to the following equation:
$$ \lambda p_1 + \mu p_2 + \nu p_3 = 0
$$

Comment: Thank you for your help, that has been very helpful too! Is there a name for the last equation you mentioned?

Comment: @Julien It is the definition for linear independence.